# Issue calling Cloud Function (Python 3.7) runtime from Apigee

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, apigee

I have created a very simple hello-world cloud function in Python 3.7. This function works fine when I call it directly from browser, or in testing mode, or via any other client.

Invoking same function using Google Apigee cloud function extension returns an error 400 Bad Request, The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. This error is getting generated on request.get_json line within cloud function.

What is different between invoking Cloud function via Apigee and how to resolve this error?

(Google cloud function is default hello-world python 3.7 sample)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/400-ssl-certificate-error

Comment: Could you log the error that the Cloud Function generates and share it in your question so that we can check a more detailed description of what happened?